# Looking for a rentability expression on excel

Tags: excel, math, economics

I'm looking for an expression who tell me which "City" got the best "price" in terms of "miles".
 The best "city" is where "price" and "miles" are lower.
Here my table :

[image]

Comment: What should be the expected result?

Comment: And why?  Which has more weight, Miles or Price?

Comment: The name of the "city" where combination of "price" and "miles" are lower

Comment: what do you mean by combination?  Should we multiply them, add them or concatenate them?

Comment: Shouldn't you be taking the `Average of Miles / Price` to see what City is best? Confusing on what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: in fact it's to calculate the best offer for cars. "City" is just the location where they are. The best offer is naturally where "price" and "miles" are lower.

Comment: I get it now. The `Miles` is the amount of miles on the car and the `Price` is the list price of the car to purchase. Is that correct?

Comment: Shouldn't you have the Year, Make and Model of the cars as well? That would weight heavily on the best miles and price.

Comment: Again, should we put more weight on the price or the miles? For example I am cheap and therefore to me the best outcome would be the 86000 for 4000, because 100 is not enough to offset the extra 12500 miles.  Or should we simply use a ration of miles per price.  Which would return the first one.

Comment: Oh yes, put more weight on the price. This is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to choose weights for this to make sense. We can set the weight of miles to 1 and then you can choose some other weight (greater than 1, since you say you care more about price) for price. Put this in, say, F5. Then for Valence (which I'll assume is in A3, you can adjust as needed) type this formula in D3:

```
=B3 + $F$5*C3
```

Or nicer still, make a named range named `priceWeight` so you can write

```
=B3 + priceWeight*C3
```

Now drag this formula down across all rows. You can find the minimum with `=MIN(D3:D8)` (replace with the range of the formulas you created above) and then find the city/cities with the lowest weight. You can even flag them with a formula or conditional highlighting if you want.

The weight should be thought of as "how many additional miles are you willing to take on to save $1" (or whatever unit of currency you're using). With these numbers Nice will be best if the weight is very low, Valence will be best if the weight is very high, and you may get others with intermediate weights.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column next to price and use formula"=(miles/price)" and then use min function to get the minimum value from the newly created column and can use index match function for finding the most economical city

Comment: Not really because if you take 98500 for 3900€ you will get 25,26  and for try take 98 500 for 6000€ you will get 16,42.<br /> So the best offer is, by you, 16,42 and this is not because i can get the same 98500 just for 3900 €

Comment: Sorry instead of using min use max function so that you will get the max miles per dollar spent so in that way you will get correct output